# JSON encoded data from PHP, doesn't display right when callback from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

My HTML/jQuery Code

```
<div id="divResult"></div>

function doSearch(str){
var jsonString = str;//$.parseJSON//JSON.stringify(str);
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'search.php',
    data:{data:jsonString},
    success:function(data){
        for( var key in data ) {
      alert(key);
    }       
});
}
```

My problem is that when I tried to parse the JSON (display it) I'm not getting the expected result, The data gets displyed in a manner of per text per line eg.

The JSON data was [{"userid:1,name:paul"},{"userid:5,name:jackson"}]

The display on the browser is like this,

```
[
{
"
u
s
e
r
i
d
:
1
```

and so on so forth...

I can't understand? is there something wrong?

I tried my js code with jsFiddle and it looks good,

I expect something like these;

```
1 Paul
5 Jackson
```

PHP Code is;

```
if ($stmt->execute(array("%$_GET[data]%"))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {    
    $aResult[] = array(
        'userid'    => $row['ui_userid'],
        'category'  => $row['ui_jocategory']
        );
        //print_r($aResult);
  }  
  echo json_encode($aResult);
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: try: `alert(data[key].userid);`

Comment: I think the problem is in the quotes, can you please post the var as prepared from server, and the dump of the array you are encoding?

Comment: @Vytautas: Im getting undefined as an alert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax options.

Comment: i think this did the trick, however, just to fix myself, i've been trying that before but (well maybe got jumbled somewhere), why do i need the dataType option for the $.ajax?

Comment: Because your php script returns JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

The better solution might be to add a

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

at the PHP side, [specifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) the data type of the response. This way jQuery will automatically know to parse the response into an object without need to specify `dataType: "json"` from the client side.